# merging two relations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This should be easy I think...

A Organisation has an Owner and Members - both are Users.

This is setup by the organisation using class_name: "User", like so:

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
   has_many :organisations_users
   has_many :members, class_name: "User", through: :organisations_users, source: :user
end
```

This works but I need an all_members function (or scope) so I can get back both owner and members in one array (or ActiveRecord object). I thought this would be trivial but it's actually not.

I've tried:

```
def all_members
   members << owner
end
```

this of course is not what I want at all... this adds the owner to the staff every time I call it.

```
def all_members
   [owner, members]
end
```

this sort of works but returns a nested array which is hard to access properly.

```
  scope :all_members, joins(:members).merge(:owner)
```

this doesn't work at all. Probably nonsense.

```
  def all_members
     members_array = members.dup
     members_array << owner
  end
```

This still permanently alters the members to include the owner?!!

Help! (Thanks)

Comment: You can write your method as `[*members, owner]` by using splat operator (`*`). It would be best to have a relation that will return all members with one query though.

Comment: hey, that worked! I think that might be the smallest change ever required on Stack Overflow

Comment: It still does 2 selects, which I'd aim to optimize. If you add your relations between `organisation_users` and `members` to the question, you should be able to get an acceptable answer.

Comment: concat (<<) permanently alters an object try using + instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order is not necessarily important then we can get this into a single query like so:

If Rails 5

```
def all_members
  # not sure if you could just do 
  # owner.or(members) since they are both User 
  # but it seems unlikely due to the join table 
  User.where(id: self.owner_id).or(
    User.where(id: organisation_users.select(:user_id))
  )
end
```

All versions of Rails (less than and including Rails 5) we can use `Arel` to build the more complex query

```
def all_members
  user_table = User.arel_table   
  User.where(
    users_table[:id].eq(self.owner_id).or(
       users_table[:id].in(
         organisation_users.select(:user_id).arel
       )
    )
  ) 
end
```

these will both result in the following SQL

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
WHERE 
  (users.id = [YOUR_OWNER_ID] OR 
   users.id IN (
     SELECT organisations_users.user_id 
     FROM organisations_users
     WHERE organisations_users.organisation_id = [YOUR_ORGANISATION_ID]
  ))
```

the end result will be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `User` objects.

Answer (score 1):

If getting an Array back is sufficient, then you can simply use:

```
def all_members
  [owner] + members
end
```

If you need a relation, then the simplest (but not most efficient) approach would be:

```
def all_members
  User.where(id: [owner] + members.ids)
end
```

It's not the most efficient as the SQL that gets generated may include a fairly large `IN` statement that cannot be efficiently cached by the database parser. Still, if the numbers are in the range of a few dozens, it would be enough even that relation trick.

Comment: The second case should be `User.where` not just `where` and while I haven't tested this theory I might assume that this should be `[owner.id] + members.ids` which would now result in 3 queries (fetch owner, fetch member ids, fetch Users where.)

Comment: Correct, it will result in 3 queries. Reason why I mentioned it's not extremely efficient.